# fancybox image gallery not showing on live page

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox-3

On [this page](https://seacoastresidence.com/photos.html) I have a photo gallery using fancybox. On my laptop I can see all the png photos locally but not on the lice website. In the head section I have the link to the fancybox css
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=jquery.fancybox.min.css and also at the bottom of the code before the  tag I have

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".fancybox").fancybox()});</script></body></html>.
```

this is the html for the fancybox image gallery

```html
<div class="row mb-2"><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="png" href="png/1.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial view of Rye" src="png/1.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/2.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid  lazy" alt="aerial view of property 15" src="png/2.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/3.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial view 3" src="png/3.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/4.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial view of property 5" src="images/4.png" /></div></a></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div><div class="row mb-2"><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/5.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial-property-6" src="images/5.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/6.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial-property-8" src="images/6.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/7.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial-property-11" src="images/7.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/8.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial tree" src="images/8.png" /></div></a></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div><div class="row mb-2"><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V1.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="ocean-view-living-1" src="images/V1.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V2.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="ocean-view-living-2" src="images/V2.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V3.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="ocean-view-living-1" src="images/V3.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V4.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="ocean-view-living-1" src="images/V4.png" /></div></a></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div><div class="row mb-2"><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V5.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial view of Rye" src="images/V5.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V6.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid  lazy" alt="aerial view of property 15" src="images/V6.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V10.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial view 3" src="images/V10.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V11.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial view of property 5" src="images/V11.png" /></div></a></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div><div class="row mb-2"><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V10.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial-property-6" src="images/V10.png" /></div></a></div>
<div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V13.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial tree" src="images/V13.png" /></div></a></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div><div class="row mb-2">
<div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V31.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial-property-11" src="images/V31.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V32.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial tree" src="images/V32.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V33.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial view of Rye" src="images/V33.png" /></div></a></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div><div class="row mb-2"><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V34.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial-property-6" src="images/V34.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V35.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial-property-11" src="images/V35.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V36.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial tree" src="images/V36.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V37.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial view of Rye" src="images/V37.png" /></div></a></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div><div class="row mb-2"><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V38.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial-property-6" src="images/V38.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V39.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial-property-11" src="images/V39.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V40.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial tree" src="images/V40.png" /></div></a></div><div class="col-6 col-sm-3"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="png/V41.png"><div class="img-fixed"><img class="img-fluid lazy" alt="aerial view of Rye" src="images/V41.png" /></div></a></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div></div>
```

Here is the [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) main page that I copied the css amd js lines from if you need it. Can amyone figure out why the pngs aren't loading on the live website after I uploaded it?

Answer (score 1):

It is because all of your `script` tags has [`defer`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) attribute (*it means it waits until full page is being loaded before script is triggered*) but `FancyBox` script and your last inline script doesn't contain it. It means your last script which contains `$(".fancybox").fancybox()` is being loaded before `jQuery` script which is needed to run FancyBox.

Pass `defer` attribute to all of your dependent scripts too or remove it from others.

```
<script defer src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/593a9d194e.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src=jquery.fancybox.min.js></script>
<script defer>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox()
    });
</script>
```

*Why does it work on your local laptop?* Probably your local host is fast enough (or cached) to initialize those scripts just in time.